# shiny app stops if there are >152 selectInputs when deployed over the spark server

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that at some point creates one selectInput for each column of a table data set uploaded by the user. When the input data set contains 152 columns, 152 selectInputs are produced and further analyses are done as expected. However, when the input file contains 153 or more columns, the app starts building the list of selectInputs but then stops (the screen turns grey). This problems does not occur when the app is run locally but only when it is hosted at [spark.rstudio.com](http://spark.rstudio.com). I have not found any specific errors in the log file.

Here is how the function to produce multiple selectInputs is described in server.R:

```
output$selectUI<-renderUI({ 
    if (is.null(input$taxtax)) {
      return(NULL)
    }

    progress <- Progress$new(session, min=1, max=10)
    on.exit(progress$close())

    progress$set(message = 'Preparing optional adjustment of feeding types',
             detail = 'Please wait...')

    for (i in 1:10) {
      progress$set(value = i)
      Sys.sleep(0.05)
    }

    library(gdata)
    tax<-read.xls(input$taxtax$datapath,check.names=F)
    tax[,-(1:2)]<-sapply(tax[,-(1:2)],as.character)
    tax[,-(1:2)]<-sapply(tax[,-(1:2)],as.numeric)
    names(tax)[1]<-"a"
    names(tax)[2]<-"b"

    dup<-which(duplicated(names(tax))==T)

    dupl<-length(dup)

    namesl<-length(names(tax))

    if (dupl>0) {
      duplindicator<-1
      megadupset<-vector()
      for (i in 1:dupl) {
        dupset<-which(names(tax)[1:namesl]==names(tax)[dup[i]])
        megadupset<-append(megadupset,dupset)
        dupsum<-rowSums(tax[dupset])
        dupname<-names(tax)[dupset][1]
        dupsum<-cbind(dupsum)
        colnames(dupsum)<-dupname
        tax<-cbind(tax,dupsum)
      }

      tax<-tax[-megadupset]

      del<-grep(".",names(tax),fixed=T)

      if (length(del)>0) {
        tax<-tax[-del]
      }
    }

    tax<-tax[,-1]
    dat<-read.xls("database.xls")
    if (is.null(input$additem)==F){
      datadditem<-data.frame(input$additem[-1,])
      names(datadditem)<-names(dat)
      dat<-rbind(dat,datadditem)
      dat<-dat[order(as.character(dat[,1])),]
      dat[,2]<-as.integer(dat[,2])
      dat[,3]<-as.integer(dat[,3])
      dat[,4]<-as.numeric(dat[,4])
    }

    taxa<-tax[,-1]

    c<-ncol(taxa)
    i<-1
    found<-vector()
    guess<-vector()

    for (i in 1:c)
    {
      taxon<-names(taxa)[i]
      i<-i+1
      feed<-dat[dat["taxon"]==taxon][3]
      if (is.na(feed)==TRUE) {
        found.value<-taxon
        found<-append(found,found.value)
      }
    }

    if (length(found)==0) {

      c<-ncol(taxa)
      i<-1
      feedvector<-vector()

      for (i in 1:c)
      {
        taxon<-names(taxa)[i]
        if (dat[dat["taxon"]==taxon][5]=="") {
          feed<-dat[dat["taxon"]==taxon][3]
        } else {
          feed<-paste(dat[dat["taxon"]==taxon][3],dat[dat["taxon"]==taxon][5],sep="")
        }
        feedvector<-append(feedvector,feed)
        i<-i+1
      }

      # sorting
      sort<-order(substr(feedvector,1,1),names(taxa))

      i<-1
      for (i in 1:c) {
        if (feedvector[i]==1) feedvector[i]<-"Herbivores"
        if (feedvector[i]=="1a") feedvector[i]<-"Herbivores - sedentary parasites"
        if (feedvector[i]=="1b") feedvector[i]<-"Herbivores - migratory endoparasites"
        if (feedvector[i]=="1c") feedvector[i]<-"Herbivores - semi-endoparasites"
        if (feedvector[i]=="1d") feedvector[i]<-"Herbivores - ectoparasites"
        if (feedvector[i]=="1e") feedvector[i]<-"Herbivores - epidermal/root hair     feeders"
        if (feedvector[i]=="1f") feedvector[i]<-"Herbivores - algal/lichen/moss feeders"
        if (feedvector[i]==2) feedvector[i]<-"Fungivores"
        if (feedvector[i]==3) feedvector[i]<-"Bacterivores"
        if (feedvector[i]==5) feedvector[i]<-"Predators"
        if (feedvector[i]==7) feedvector[i]<-"Animal parasites (dispersal stages)"
        if (feedvector[i]==8) feedvector[i]<-"Omnivores"
      }

      x<-length(feedvector)
      outputlist<-list()
      i<-1

      for (i in sort) {
        output<-selectInput(paste("feed",i,sep=""), colnames(taxa)[i], 
                            c("Herbivores - sedentary parasites"="1a","Herbivores - migratory endoparasites"="1b","Herbivores - semi-endoparasites"="1c","Herbivores - ectoparasites"="1d","Herbivores - epidermal/root hair feeders"="1e","Herbivores - algal/lichen/moss feeders"="1f","Fungivores"=2,"Bacterivores"=3,"Predators"=5,"Animal parasites (dispersal stages)"=7,"Omnivores"=8),
                            selected=feedvector[i])
        outputlist<-append(outputlist,output)
      }

      outputlist

    } else {return(NULL)}

  })
```

The corresponding line in ui.R:

```
htmlOutput(selectUI)
```